# Skip multiple lines while parsing file in python and storing their values

Tags: python, string, parsing, data-processing

I apologize for the confusing title. I'm very new to Python and here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm parsing a file file.txt that has data like this (and other stuff):

file.txt:

```
...
a = (
1
2
3 )
...
```

I need to store this type of data in 2 parts:

name = "a"

value = {"(", "1", "2", "3 )"}
^ each line is an element of the list

I'm parsing the file line by line as shown in the snippet below and I can't change that. I'm not sure how to store the data this way by looking ahead a few lines, storing their values and then skipping them so that they're not processed twice. **I want the 2 variables name and value populated when the loop is at the first line "a = "**

```
with open(file.txt) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        ...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a dictionary:

```
txt=open(r"file.txt","r").readlines()
dictionary=dict()
for i in range(len(txt)):
    if "=" in txt[i]:
        name,values=txt[i].split()[0],[txt[i].split()[-1]]
        dictionary[name],i={"name":name},i+1
        while True:
            values.append(txt[i])
            if ")" in txt[i]:
                break
            i=i+1
        values=[value.replace("\n","") for value in values]
        dictionary[name].update({"values":values})
        i=i-1
    i=i+1

>>dictionary["a"]
Out[40]: {'name': 'a', 'values': ['(', '1', '2', '3 )']}
>>dictionary["b"]
Out[45]: {'name': 'b', 'values': ['(', '3', '4', '6 )']}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you parse the file line-to-line. Whenever you find an equal sign "=" in a line, it means that the char before the "=" is the name value you want. Then the next line is the first element of the list, the line after that the second element etc... when a line has the char ")" it means that it is the last value of the list.
[See the Python string.find method for this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). Try to understand the concept and the coding shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
[u'a']
['(', '1', '2', '3', ')']
```

Is this what you need?

Then you can follow these lines of code:

```
import nltk

name = []
value = []
with open("file.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        words = line.split()
        if ('(') in words:
            name.append(words[0].decode('utf-8'))
            value.append('(')
        else:
            for entry in words:
                value.append(entry)

print (name)
print (value)

fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too large, read whole file into memory then use a while loop to do a finer-grained control:

```
# python3
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    index = 0
    while True:
        # do something here
```

Else, if only last value contains ')', do this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    pairs = []
    for line in f:
        values = []
        name, value = line.strip().split('=')
        name = name.strip()
        values.append(value.strip())
        while True:
            line = next(f)
            values.append(line.strip())
            if ')' in line:
                break
        pairs.append((name, values))
```